# How to query a mongodb with nodejs for a case insensitive search/string containing substring search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

so I want to search my db for a job 'title. It's working however only if the exact string matches, I would like the search to be case insensitive as well as find the string in the database if ti contains some of the search query.

I looked around and saw the regex might work for the casing problem but I'm unsure how I'd implement it with what I already have.

**Jobs.route**

```
router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {

let query = {}; 

let tmp = req.query;


if (tmp && tmp != undefined && Object.keys(tmp).length != 0) {
    query = tmp;
}   

let jobs = await Job.find(query)
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 }); 

if (!jobs) {
    return res.status(400).send({
        message: `Encountered an error when getting job with title ${req.query.title}.`,
        ok: false,
        errors: [error],
        jobs: {}
    });
} else {
    return res.send({
        total_items: jobs.length,
        message: `Returned all jobs with title ${req.query.title} successfully`,
        ok: true,
        errors: [],
        jobs: jobs
    });
}
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Kindly provide with the `req.query`

Answer (score 0):

First You will have to add an index ($text) to the collection.

Refer : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

```
db.articles.createIndex( { subject: "text" } )
```

Once done, update the query to

```
Jobs.find({ $text: { $search: "Developer" } }) //Software being the Job Title
```

In Current Code: req.query -> "{ $text: { $search: "Developer" } }";

This will help you gain documents with matching titles like ->

```
[ "SOFTWARE DEVELOPER", "Software Developer", "software developer" , "SoftWare DeveLoPer" , "BackEnd Developer" , "Developer In Test" ....]
```